# SQL Developer not opening specific folder path set at preferences

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have set a default path to look for scripts. 
But on a new worksheet  Ctrl+o doesn't open the default folder and leads to temp folder location, whereas ctrl+S opens to the default path set at preferences.

Both actions should lead to the same folder right.
Is my understanding correct ?
What should i do to correct this ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That preference tells sql developer where to look for scripts when you execute them, via

```
@script.sql
```

It has no bearing on what folders you see when opening or saving a file.

Now, once you do open a file from that directory, the next time you go to Open/Save a file, you'll see that directory listed on the left for quicker navigation.

[image]

Comment: Actually, it used to list all the recently opened folders in quicker navigation. But to improve the performance of the tool,i disabled some features after that this quicker navigation window isnt listing any folders.

Comment: what did you disable?

Comment: FYI i have added one more picture in question to show the disabled features.

Comment: disabling the entirety of database is causing you to lose usability in favor of maybe a slight increase of performance. better bang for your buck to disable only say migrations and data miner and try that for starters.

Comment: Will try that. Thank you 